How to Save Pictures Taken from a Flutter App to a Computer Directory and Send them to a Flask Server?
I'm developing a Flutter app where users take pictures using their phone's camera and they can send it forward to flask code for processing using the send image option. I want to implement a feature where these pictures are saved to a directory on my computer and then sent to a Flask server for further processing. How can I achieve this?
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras = []; // Initialize to an empty list
CameraController? _controller; // Add "?" to indicate it can be null
File? _imageFile; // Add "?" to indicate it can be null
String _ngrokUrl = 'https://73b4-182-176-222-244.ngrok-free.app'; // Pre-set with your ngrok URL

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Smart Attendance System',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AttendancePage(),
    );
  }
}

class AttendancePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AttendancePageState createState() => _AttendancePageState();
}

class _AttendancePageState extends State<AttendancePage> {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final TextEditingController _urlController = TextEditingController(text: _ngrokUrl); // Initialize with ngrok URL

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    if (cameras.length > 0) {
      _controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
      await _controller!.initialize(); // Add "!" to indicate it's not null
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    try {
      final image = await _controller!.takePicture();
      final imageFile = File(image.path);
      final savePath = 'C:/Users/arzoo/Desktop/folder/saved_pictures';
      await Directory(savePath).create(recursive: true); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
      await imageFile.copy('$savePath/image_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = imageFile;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      _showSnackBar('Failed to take picture: $e');
    }
  }
  
  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    final imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    final savePath = 'C:/Users/arzoo/Desktop/folder/saved_pictures';
    await Directory(savePath).create(recursive: true); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    await imageFile.copy('$savePath/image_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = imageFile;
    });
  }
}

  Future<void> _sendImage() async {
    if (_imageFile == null || !_imageFile!.existsSync()) {
      _showSnackBar('No image file available or file does not exist');
      return;
    }

    if (_ngrokUrl.isEmpty) {
      _showSnackBar('Please set the ngrok URL first');
      return;
    }

    final url = Uri.parse(_ngrokUrl + '/upload'); // Use the dynamically set ngrok URL
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
      ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', _imageFile!.path));

    try {
      var response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        _showSnackBar('Image sent successfully: $responseData');
      } else {
        var errorData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
        print('Failed with status: ${response.statusCode}. Response body: $errorData');
        _showSnackBar('Failed to send image: $errorData');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending image: $e');
      _showSnackBar('Error sending image: $e');
    }
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Smart Attendance System'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Please enter the ngrok URL below. Ngrok is used for tunneling and exposing your local server to the internet.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              TextField(
                controller: _urlController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter ngrok URL',
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _ngrokUrl = value.trim(); // Update the ngrok URL on change
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              _imageFile == null
                  ? (_controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized
                  ? CameraPreview(_controller!) // Add "!" to indicate it's not null
                  : Container())
                  : Image.file(_imageFile!), // Add "!" to indicate it's not null
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _takePicture,
                child: Text('Take Picture'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _pickImage,
                child: Text('Pick Image'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _sendImage,
                child: Text('Send Image'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
 this is my code, it doesnt send image forward. i have specified port in my app.py file


Unless the PC and mobile are on the same local network, it is not possible to send a file from phone to PC without assigning the PC a static IP, using another remote server as slingshot or some hack involving a free cloud storage like GDrive, Dropbox etc. and some scripts on the PC.
